# How to apply a ratelimit in rspamd using a selector that matches the sender with domains from a list?

Tags: rspamd

I have created a map

```
UNPOLITE_SENDERS_MAP {
    type="selector";
    symbol="UNPOLITE_SENDER"
    selector = 'from("smtp","orig"):domain.get_tld';
    score = 3.5;
    map="/etc/rspamd/local.d/maps.d/unpolite_senders_expr";
    message="Detected un unusal ammount of email, please take a break"; 
    }
```

and the senders are correctly matched against that map. (Can be seen in the logs)

I have tried to apply a rate limit based on that map using

```
other_limit = {
      selector = "emails:apply_map('UNPOLITE_SENDERS_MAP')";
      bucket = [{
        symbol = "LOCAL_RATE_10_30";
        burst = 3;
        rate = "10/30s";
        message = "Unusual message rate 10-30, please take a break";
        }]
```

However that rate limit is not being applied.

The configurations are in the proper places. I cannot configure a rete based on a map and for sure I'm missing something with the selector part of the rate limit configuration.

Any ideas?